# Force Close: requires android.permission.onlyusebyphone

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-logcat, android-permissions

I'm getting an error in my logcat stating: requires android.permission.onlyusebyphone and I'm not sure why this might be. I have the correct permissions set (shown below) and I understand you can't edit the APN settings in ICS+ but you should be able to at least open the APN settings menu using the following:

SOURCE:

```
        } else if (v == mAssistInstrButton) {
            // "LET'S DO THIS" Button in final instructions screen for ICS and
            // up is selected
            Values = getValues();
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS));
            try {
                showNotification();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finish();
```

LOGCAT:

```
    09-09 10:31:49.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3007): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    09-09 10:31:49.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3007): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission  Denial: starting Intent { act=android.settings.APN_SETTINGS  cmp=com.android.settings/.ApnSettings } from ProcessRecord{42a1fa58 3007:com.sample.project.datasettings/u0a84} (pid=3007, uid=10084)      
    09-09 10:31:49.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3007):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
    09-09 10:31:49.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3007):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
    09-09 10:31:49.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3007):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1761)
    09-09 10:31:49.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3007):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1411)
    09-09 10:31:49.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3007):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
    09-09 10:31:49.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3007):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
    09-09 10:31:49.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3007):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522)
    09-09 10:31:49.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3007):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490)
    09-09 10:31:49.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3007):     at com.sample.project.datasettings.ConfigFinalActivity.onClick(ConfigFinalActivity.java:199)
    09-09 10:31:49.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3007):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
    09-09 10:31:49.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3007):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
    09-09 10:31:49.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3007):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    09-09 10:31:49.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3007):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    09-09 10:31:49.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3007):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    09-09 10:31:49.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3007):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4795)
    09-09 10:31:49.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3007):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    09-09 10:31:49.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3007):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    09-09 10:31:49.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3007):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    09-09 10:31:49.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3007):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
    09-09 10:31:49.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3007):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Manifest:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sample.project.datasettings"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="1.3" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/notifications_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.sample.project.datasettings.StartActivity"
            android:label="@string/display_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.sample.project.datasettings.UpdateActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.sample.project.datasettings.ConfigFinalActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation">
        </activity>
            <activity
            android:name="com.sample.project.datasettings.MySSLSocketFactory"
            android:configChanges="orientation">
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.sample.project.datasettings.NotificationActivityForMultiProf"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" >
        </activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: Working fine on Nexus 4. What kind of device are you testing against?

Comment: MAKE: zte MODEL: z660g

Comment: Must be a that specific model related issue. OEM issue :) Did you check in emulator?

Comment: Nailed it... I tried a few other devices and the issue is isolated to the device

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have an Permission missing or not works.
Maybe it's the known bug with WRITE_APN_SETTINGS

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24227

Comment: It's not using WRITE_APN_SETTINGS
It's using ACTION_APN_SETTINGS

Comment: You can't write APN settings with ICS+ devices but you can certainly open the APN menu under settings